# Native geolocation do not execute catch

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to use native geolocation from Ionic, but when it can´t get the location, don´t execute the catch method, it don´t do nothing.  This is my code:

```ts
let options: {timeout:10000, enableHighAccurary:true}

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
.then ((resp) =>{

  this.latitud = resp.coords.latitude;
  this.longitud = resp.coords.longitude;

  console.log(this.latitud+"-------"+this.longitud);

  })

.catch((error) =>{
  console.log("Error getting location: "+error)
  })
```

Comment: is this in any specific device?

Comment: @SurajRao No, it happend with all devices that I have try.